# Getting Date Parsing Value as NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to parsing date in angular for following

```
$scope.startDate = '2016-12-16 15:11:52'
$start = Date.parse($filter('date')($scope.startDate,'dd-MM-yyyy'));
```

but getting value as `NaN`.

Comment: Use `moment.js` to parse it,
momentjs.com

Comment: What you mean by $start?

Comment: use moment js. Will help on this http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Comment: i think it's just enough $filter('date')($scope.startDate,'dd-MM-yyyy')

Comment: you can just do `$scope.startDate = new Date('2016-12-16 15:11:52')` and `{{startDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}` where ever you want to use the date

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of yours

```
  $scope.startDate =  '2016-12-16 15:11:52'  
  $start = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.startDate.replace("-","/")),'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Reason

filter is format only date object. but you has been pass string type. So we need convert string to date time. the `new Date()` is not convert to `(-)` this format. so I have use replace `(-)` to `(/)` . Now it's working. I have tested in

Demo on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBEQQ9FT6G1U)